# HTTParty Post paramters array of hashes becoming array

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am using HTTParty in Ruby to make a Post call.
The server expects to see data in the format:

```
{
   "param1": 100,
   "params": [
      {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2"
      },
      {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

My hash in ruby looks like this

```
{
   "param1"=> 100,
   "params"=> [
      {
          "key1"=> "value1",
          "key2"=> "value2"
      },
      {
          "key1"=> "value1",
          "key2"=> "value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am making this call

```
class Http
    include HTTParty
end

Http.post(url, {:body => my_hash})
```

However, the array of hashes is coming incorrectly as

```
{
   "param1": 100,
   "params": [
          "value1",
          "value2",
          "value1",
          "value2"
   ]
}
```

Could someone please help me out on this?

Comment: I'm hesitant to offer a suggestion, as I'm not familiar with `HTTParty`, but I did find [this example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb). As it appears virtually identical to what you have (the new form of expressing the hash elements is used, but a hash is a hash), I thought this part might be relevant: "Note that "skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token" must be set in the "pears" controller for this example". If I'm way off base let me know and I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to pass headers as application/json and pass the params as json by using to_json